# Showing $g(x) = \frac{x}{1-|x|}$ is continuous on (-1,+1)

Tags: real-analysis

In showing that $g(x) = \frac{x}{1-|x|}$ is continuous on $(-1,+1)$ I'm not entirely sure whether I can use the property that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ providing both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous on $(a,b)$ and $g(x) \neq 0$, $\forall x \in (a,b)$ (also, my book/lecture notes actually only define this property for a point, not on an interval, but I can't see why it can't be used on an interval).

Also, I tried going to the definition of continuity and showing that $\forall p \in (-1,+1)$ and $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall x \in (-1,+1)$ such that $|x-p| < \delta$

$|g(x) - g(p)| < \epsilon$

$\bigg| \displaystyle\frac{x}{1-|x|} - \frac{p}{1-|p|}\bigg| < \epsilon$

$\bigg|\displaystyle\frac{x-x|p|-p+p|x|}{1-|p|-|x|+|xp|}\bigg| < \epsilon$

But after this I get stuck as to where to take it.

Also, earlier on in the question I showed that $g(x)$ is 1-1 and thought this could be used, somehow, in showing that $g$ is continuous on the interval but also showing the function is monotone doesn't imply continuity so I'm not sure it's going to be of any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Functions are continuous at points and if a function $f$ is continuous in every point of a set $A$, we say the function is continuous on $A$.

Comment: @leo Thanks. I'm aware of the convention and couldn't see any reason it couldn't be extended to an interval but thought I'd double check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The absolute value is continuous, sums, differences, products and quotients (where defined!) of continuous functions are continuous, hence $g$ is continuous where it is defined (that is on $\mathbb R\setminus\{-1,1\}$).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have any ideas in regards to trying to show it from the definition of continuity, i.e. if there's some simple trick to get that fraction down to something much simpler?

Comment: showing this by definition can get pretty messy. Probably you need to seperate several cases and I would'nt write $>\epsilon$ there since you should determine $\delta$ first

Comment: @Noble. Try to prove that the function $t\mapsto 1/t$ is continuous at $p$ if $p\neq 0 $. Then you can use that composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the functions as: $$f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x},~x\in[0,1),~~~~f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x},~x\in(-1,0]$$
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. Doing it this way actually makes it pretty straightforward proving continuity. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice! +++++++++++++++++